# What happened to Voldemort's first body (corpse)?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

We have seen that the use of "Avada Kedavra" produces a green flash and a dead body.  When Voldemort comes to Godric's Hollow, he kills James and Lily, whose bodies are now buried in the church graveyard, and attempts to kill Harry.  Of course, the curse rebounds back to Voldemort, 'killing' him.  Many years later, Voldemort and Peter recreate a body for Voldemort.

Is there anything, anywhere that says what might have happened to the Voldemort's original body/corpse?